# $J \neq 0$ ideal in $R=\mathbb{Z}[i]$. show that $J \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If $J \neq 0$ is an ideal in $R=\mathbb{Z}[i] .$ Then I need to show that $J \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

My approach (Or the way I wanted to approach the problem):

In order for $J \cap \mathbb{Z}$ to be an ideal, I need to show it's an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$,
and that $\lambda x\in J \cap \mathbb{Z}$; for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in J \cap \mathbb{Z}$.

But I really don't know how to show it in such a general case, when I don't know anything about the elements in J.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: But you know plenty about the elements of $J$. You know that if you add two elements of $J$, you get an element of $J$; you know the additive inverse of every element of $J$ is in $J$; you know that if you multiply an element of $J$ by an element of $R$, you get an element of $J$. What more could you possibly want to know about the elements of $J$?

Comment: To be clear, apply the proof I linked to the inclusion map.

Comment: Making any progress, sjm?